# Как в Git можно удалить мусорную историю?

Tags: git, github

Скажем, вот у меня есть отдельная ветка, которая идеально работает на моей машине, я ее коммичу и пушу в github.

Далее пытаюсь развернуть через TeamCity, но он почему-то падает и вот с этого момента я начинаю вносить небольшие правки в какой-нибудь конфигурационный файл сборки и пушить, а потом повторно разворачивать через TeamCity, пока не найду все косяки.

В итоге, в истории много мусора...

Какие есть варианты решения этой проблемы, чтобы при мерже весь этот мусор не попал в основную ветку?

Comment: А банальный Squash and Merge не достаточно? https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits

Answer (score 2):

`amend` - идеально подойдёт для добавления изменений в последний существующий коммит. Только нужно будет `force push`, выполнить, чтобы стереть предыдущий.

Если нужно соединить все коммиты в один, то вам поможет `squash`, а если нужно удалить существующие коммиты, то вам нужно использовать `rebase` в интерактивном моде.

Comment: +1 за интерактивный rebase. И уточнение: интерактивный rebase позволяет не только удалить, а еще много чего. В контексте вопроса актуально будет то, что позволяет слить какие-то комиты и/или разделить существующие. Главное, можно оставить код в том состоянии, в котором он сейчас, но изменить то, какие комиты были сделаны, чтобы прийти к текущему состоянию. Одним словом переписать историю.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin +